# Empty response body in controllers specs RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

There is the following code of RSpec controllers spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::PostsController do
  let!(:post) { create(:post) }

  describe 'index' do
    it 'should return a json array of posts' do
      get :index, format: :json
      puts "response=#{ response.body }"
      result = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(result[0][:title]).to eq(post.title)
    end
  end
end
```

Code of the controller:

```
class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

But I got the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: result = JSON.parse(response.body)
 JSON::ParserError:
   A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
```

The body of the response is empty. So, tell me please, how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render :json => @posts
end
```